# Multiple queries in Pie Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a pie chart in asp.net mvc however when I'm trying to fetch the data from sql it displays multiple queries save in database, is their a way to get sum of multiple same queries and load the sum in the pie chart

```
@(Html.EJS().AccumulationChart("container5")
       .Series(sr =>
     {
     sr.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.AccumulationType.Pie)
     .XName("Heading")
     .YName("Factor_Score")
     .Name("Factor_Score")
     .Explode(true)
     .DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Name("Factor_Score").Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.AccumulationLabelPosition.Outside).ConnectorStyle(cs => cs.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ConnectorType.Line).Length("5 %")).Font(ft => ft.Size("14px")))
                    .Animation(animate => animate.Enable(true))
                    .Radius("70%")
                    .StartAngle(0)
                    .EndAngle(360)
                    .InnerRadius("0%")
                    .GroupTo("9")
                    .GroupMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.GroupModes.Point)
                    .DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource1).Add();
                    })
                     .EnableSmartLabels(true)
                     .Tooltip(tp => tp.Enable(true))
                     .LegendSettings(leg => leg.Visible(true)).Title("Loan Audit Finding Detail Checklist").Render()
```

Controller:

```
string a = Heading;                     
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Factor_Score);
PieChartData_Data_View.Add(new PieChartSourceDataData_View(a, b));
```

[[image: Sample Ouput][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voKJt.png)
[image: SQL]

Comment: Are you retrieving the content from a database? Can you show the controller Action for this?

Comment: string a = Heading;                    
  int b = Convert.ToInt32(Factor_Score);

  PieChartData_Data_View.Add(new PieChartSourceDataData_View(a, b));

Comment: Yes, I retrieve the content form database

Comment: See my example below. You have do more in the controller to get the correct data you want.

Comment: It would help to see your ViewBag.dataSource. I found an example that looks simular to what you have but it is using static data in the controller. There has to be more to your controller action than you posted.

Answer (score 0):

For me to give you a complete example I would have to see the whole controller Action. But I assume you would do something like this in the contoller action.

```
 var whateverYouWant = db.YourTable.ToList();
 foreach(var arm in whateverYouWant)
 {
    var sum = arm.ArmQuestions.Count();
 }
```

You would have to load all the categories you wanted to count. You could also do this with a better query like I had posted but without seeing everything, im doing it blind..